# SQL LOOP Equivalent Function

Tags: sql, oracle, loops

I'm brand new to posting here so apologies if I forgot to include something that would help you help me.

I am aware that there is no native LOOP function in SQL, but I am looking for a way to do something equivalent. I am not looking for a pl/sql solution. The data that I need to work with is ~pseudo-data~ that I have created as a result of the existing data. I'm typically savvy enough to find the right answer and get it implemented but in this case I've been searching for a couple of days and the solutions I've found for other similar questions either don't work for me or I'm just not smart enough to apply them correctly. The data I have access to is quite ugly and is essentially a row-by-row print out from a mainframe application.

```
    select
      nmh.trn_date, nmh.trn_number, nmh.trn_timestamp, nmh.hist_no, nmh.sub_hist_no, nmh.entry_type, nmh.que_line_id, nmh.details, nmh.details_next
    , (case
        when nmh.details_next like 'MATCH REF:%' then 0
        when nmh.details_next = '*STOP MATCH OVERRIDE' then 1
        when nmh.details_next != '*STOP MATCH OVERRIDE' then 2
        else null
      end) as blocking_initial
    from (
      --'next' message history (nmh)
      select
        bmh.trn_date, bmh.trn_number, bmh.trn_timestamp, bmh.hist_no, bmh.sub_hist_no, bmh.entry_type, bmh.que_line_id, bmh.details
      , lead(bmh.details,1,null) over (partition by bmh.trn_date, bmh.trn_number, bmh.trn_timestamp order by bmh.hist_no, bmh.sub_hist_no) as details_next
      from (
        --blocking message history (bmh)
        select mh2.trn_date, mh2.trn_number, mh2.trn_timestamp, mh2.hist_no, mh2.sub_hist_no, mh2.entry_type, mh2.que_line_id, mh2.details
        from rgw.message_hist_t mh2
          inner join (
            --distinct message history (dmh)
            select distinct mh1.trn_date, mh1.trn_number, mh1.trn_timestamp
            from rgw.message_hist_t mh1
            where mh1.que_line_id like '%_OFACQ' and mh1.trn_date = to_date('20150526','yyyymmdd')
          ) dmh on dmh.trn_date = mh2.trn_date and dmh.trn_number = mh2.trn_number and dmh.trn_timestamp = mh2.trn_timestamp
      ) bmh
      order by bmh.trn_date, bmh.trn_number, bmh.hist_no, bmh.sub_hist_no
    ) nmh
    where nmh.details like 'MATCH REF:%'
    order by nmh.hist_no desc, nmh.sub_hist_no desc
    ;
```

The above query creates a column of pseudo-data called **blocking_initial** which gives me values of 0, 1, and 2. I need to override all values of "0" and some values of "2" depending upon the preceding value(s).

---

Below is a sample of the result set along with a column to the very right called **blocking_status** which shows the value I am ultimately trying to produce; this is not part of the result set. I added spaces between what I would call each sequence of loop logic (explained below) to hopefully make it a bit easier to follow visually.

```
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    ¦    TRN_DATE    ¦ TRN_NUMBER ¦ TRN_TIMESTAMP ¦ HIST_NO ¦ SUB_HIST_NO ¦ ENTRY_TYPE ¦ QUE_LINE_ID ¦           DETAILS           ¦        DETAILS_NEXT         ¦ BLOCKING_INITIAL ¦ BLOCKING_STATUS ¦
    ¦----------------+------------+---------------+---------+-------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------+-----------------¦
    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      90 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/725449(OFAC) ¦ XYZ in FLD 70               ¦                2 ¦               2 ¦

    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      87 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: ENT/3946(OFAC)   ¦ *STOP MATCH OVERRIDE        ¦                1 ¦               1 ¦
    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      86 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: ENT/3945(OFAC)   ¦ MATCH REF: ENT/3946(OFAC)   ¦                0 ¦               1 ¦
    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      83 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/380212(OFAC) ¦ XYZ in FLD 50F              ¦                2 ¦               1 ¦
    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      82 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/380170(OFAC) ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/380212(OFAC) ¦                0 ¦               1 ¦
    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      81 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/380161(OFAC) ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/380170(OFAC) ¦                0 ¦               1 ¦

    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      78 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/380212(OFAC) ¦ XYZ in FLD 50F              ¦                2 ¦               2 ¦
    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      77 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/380170(OFAC) ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/380212(OFAC) ¦                0 ¦               2 ¦
    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      76 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/380161(OFAC) ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/380170(OFAC) ¦                0 ¦               2 ¦

    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      72 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/380212(OFAC) ¦ XYZ in ORP ADDRESS          ¦                2 ¦               2 ¦
    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      71 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/380170(OFAC) ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/380212(OFAC) ¦                0 ¦               2 ¦
    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      70 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/380161(OFAC) ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/380170(OFAC) ¦                0 ¦               2 ¦

    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      67 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/85230(OFAC)  ¦ XYZ in OBK ADDRESS          ¦                2 ¦               2 ¦

    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      64 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/239098(OFAC) ¦ XYZ in OBK ADDRESS          ¦                2 ¦               2 ¦

    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      61 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: ENT/3945(OFAC)   ¦ *STOP MATCH OVERRIDE        ¦                1 ¦               1 ¦
    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      58 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/418525(OFAC) ¦ XYZ in DBT ADDRESS          ¦                2 ¦               1 ¦

    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      56 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/725449(OFAC) ¦ XYZ in ORIG TO BNF INFO     ¦                2 ¦               2 ¦

    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      54 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/69756(OFAC)  ¦ XYZ in CDT ADDRESS          ¦                2 ¦               2 ¦

    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      51 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/485596(OFAC) ¦ XYZ in CDT ADDRESS          ¦                2 ¦               2 ¦

    ¦ 5/26/2015 0:00 ¦        519 ¦ 2.01505E+22   ¦      48 ¦           0 ¦ MEM        ¦ *SYS_MEMO   ¦ MATCH REF: JMA/753087(OFAC) ¦ XYZ in CDT ADDRESS          ¦                2 ¦               2 ¦
    +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

Here is the logic behind how the values need to be looped through and updated (hopefully I've translated my brain in a way the rest of you understand):

- The fields that make up the *master* group/partition are the trn_date, trn_number, and trn_timestamp (first three columns). I am calling this the master set as it represents all pertinent data for this particular item as a whole.

  - The table above only shows one example group but imagine the same set of data being repeated (for example purposes only as each set has the potential to be unique) for trn_values of 888, 1234, etc...
- The first value of each master group/partition can only be a 1
  or a 2.
- A 1 can precede either a 0 or a 2.
- A 2 can precede a 0, 1, or 2.
- A 0 (or set of 0's) will always belong to the preceding value, whether a 1 or a 2.
- All of the 1's should be interrogated **first** in order to ensure all values are converted properly.

  - If the 1 is followed by a single or multiple 0's, all of those 0's belong to the 1 and should be turned into 1's.
  - The next value (whether 0's exist or not) will always be a 2. This 2 will also need to be turned into a 1.

    - If there are any 0's that belong to this 2 they will also need to be turned into 1's.
    - This ends the loop sequence that any additional values after this first 2 (and associated 0's) should not be interrogated as part of this sequence.
- After all of the 1's have been handled, the 2's should be interrogated.

  - If the 2 is followed by a single or multiple 0's, all of those 0's belong to the 2 and should be turned into 2's.
  - If the 2 is followed by anything other than a 0, that value remains as is.
- The end result will only consist of the values 1 or 2.

---

**Special Notes:**

- There is no *maximum* number of 0's that can belong to a 1 or a 2. I
  have seen examples with upwards of 50.
- There is no *maximum* number of times a 1 or 2 can exist within each master group/partition.
- It is possible that only values of 2 will exist and no changes are required.
- It is possible that only values of 2 and 0 will exist.
- It is **not** possible for a 1 to exist without a 2.

---

Ultimately, if someone sees a better way of doing this besides using this 'number sequencing' I'm attempting then I'm happy to change approach.

Hopefully nobody wants to kill me after reading through all this haha!

Comment: I haven't checked whether this would be possible or not using just (Oracle) SQL, but is there any particular reason why PL/SQL is not an option?

Comment: Could you setup your example in SQL Fiddle?  I'm also having trouble understanding your use cases as well.  If possible, could you be more specific?  For instance, you mention "The first value of each master/group partition can only be 1 or a 2", however is the "first value" a column in the table or a column you are attempting to derive?

Comment: You've given a query that produces the result set you show, but not the underlying raw data (which makes that `%_OFACQ`, and the whole thing, confusing). That query is really irrelevant to the specific question you asked about manipulating the numbers. I've attempted to infer the underlying requirement from the query though, but it would have been better for you to focus the question more, and/or provide your real requirement - rather than starting us off in the middle of a solution.

Comment: Also curious why you have a date column that seems to have the time set to midnight, and a separate 'timestamp' that seems to be a 23-digit number representing the time down to 9 decimal places; you've shown that in scientific notation which also isn't helpful, but since it starts with 201505 that seems likely. Why not just have a single column that is actually a proper timestamp?

Comment: @APC, apologies if this was still confusing but you must have failed to realize all the time invested into attempting to ensure all necessary details were provided. I'm rather confused by your statement about no rows being returned as I stated that it was the query **output**, not the sample data. You are correct that running the query against the data output would yield no results. Not sure what your grudge is against against my three extra sentences on 'cleverness' or 'apologies on length' but I'll take that into consideration should I post a question again. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the model clause to work from your intermediate result set, but using an intermediate stage might mean you're going something wrong; the fact you are setting a status flag and then changing based on surrounding data looks like it should be simpler than you're making it, particularly as everything is coming from a single fairly simple set of rows in one table.

Trying to work backwards to what you're actually ultimately trying to achieve, picking through the logic of your steps, I *think* you're trying to set the status flag to 1 if the current *or* next record - ignoring `MATCH REF :%` - is `*STOP MATCH OVERRIDE`, and 2 otherwise; and for the intervening `MATCH REF:%` records to keep the last flag, since they don't affect how it's set (zeros in your intermediate results).

If that's right, you could do that with something like this:

```
select trn_date, trn_number, trn_timestamp,
  hist_no, sub_hist_no, entry_type, que_line_id, details,
  case when details_next_2 is null
    or (details_next_1 != '*STOP MATCH OVERRIDE'
      and details_next_2 != '*STOP MATCH OVERRIDE')
    then 2 else 1 end as blocking_status
from (
  select trn_date, trn_number, trn_timestamp,
    hist_no, sub_hist_no, entry_type, que_line_id, details,
    lead(case when details like 'MATCH REF:%' then null else details end, 1) ignore nulls
        over (partition by trn_date, trn_number, trn_timestamp
          order by hist_no, sub_hist_no) as details_next_1,
    lead(case when details like 'MATCH REF:%' then null else details end, 2) ignore nulls
        over (partition by trn_date, trn_number, trn_timestamp
          order by hist_no, sub_hist_no) as details_next_2,
    count(case when que_line_id like '%_OFACQ' then que_line_id end)
        over (partition by trn_date, trn_number, trn_timestamp) as flag_count
  from message_hist_t
)
where details like 'MATCH REF:%'
and flag_count > 0
order by hist_no desc, sub_hist_no desc;
```

I've reduced the number of inner queries, and taken out the self-join, replacing it with an analytic count so the effect of that join can be achieved with a filter in the outer query (`flag_count > 0`; you can probably find a better name...) which mostly means you don't have to hit the table twice.

The two `lead()` calls are the same, except for the offset. The case statement turns the match rows into nulls, and the leading then skips those because of the `ignore nulls`.

With data that gives you your original result set in the question, this simplified query produces this output (with trn_timestamp, entry_type and que_line_id ommitted to reduce scrolling):

```
TRN_DATE   TRN_NUMBER  HIST_NO  SUB_HIST_NO DETAILS                      BLOCKING_STATUS
---------- ---------- -------- ------------ --------------------------- ----------------
2015-05-26        519       90            0 MATCH REF: JMA/725449(OFAC)                2
2015-05-26        519       87            0 MATCH REF: ENT/3946(OFAC)                  1
2015-05-26        519       86            0 MATCH REF: ENT/3945(OFAC)                  1
2015-05-26        519       83            0 MATCH REF: JMA/380212(OFAC)                1
2015-05-26        519       82            0 MATCH REF: JMA/380170(OFAC)                1
2015-05-26        519       81            0 MATCH REF: JMA/380161(OFAC)                1
2015-05-26        519       78            0 MATCH REF: JMA/380212(OFAC)                2
2015-05-26        519       77            0 MATCH REF: JMA/380170(OFAC)                2
2015-05-26        519       76            0 MATCH REF: JMA/380161(OFAC)                2
2015-05-26        519       72            0 MATCH REF: JMA/380212(OFAC)                2
2015-05-26        519       71            0 MATCH REF: JMA/380170(OFAC)                2
2015-05-26        519       70            0 MATCH REF: JMA/380161(OFAC)                2
2015-05-26        519       67            0 MATCH REF: JMA/85230(OFAC)                 2
2015-05-26        519       64            0 MATCH REF: JMA/239098(OFAC)                2
2015-05-26        519       61            0 MATCH REF: ENT/3945(OFAC)                  1
2015-05-26        519       58            0 MATCH REF: JMA/418525(OFAC)                1
2015-05-26        519       56            0 MATCH REF: JMA/725449(OFAC)                2
2015-05-26        519       54            0 MATCH REF: JMA/69756(OFAC)                 2
2015-05-26        519       51            0 MATCH REF: JMA/485596(OFAC)                2
2015-05-26        519       48            0 MATCH REF: JMA/753087(OFAC)                2
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd35d/1).

Which is the `blocking_status` value you wanted, though it's entirely possible it's a coincidence and I'm way off-base with my interpretation of what you're doing. It seems to be right for the limited data you supplied, but might not be for your entire data set.

Comment: I managed to find a solution that provides me the expected results. I will also give your solution a try to see if it yields the same across all of my items. I appreciate you taking a look.